# Splitting sqlite string

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I have a string like this: `74~1~340`. This string is the value for a column `vc_ValueAnswer`, in the table `Motor_Answers`.

I need compare the first value, `74`, with the first incoming parameter and the second value, `1`, with the second incoming parameter. If these two values are correct, then I should return the the third value `340`. Another example is `5~1~340`.

How can I separate the values for compare them? 
I'm using SQLite Maestro

Comment: Why do you think you need to separate the string? Can't you concatenate the parameters?

Comment: CL, you're correct, that is a very nice and simply solution, thanks a lot.